# webpack command not working on 32 bit system

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Hi I m running this command webpack --progress --devtool sourcemap but getting the following error in 32 bit system

ERROR in Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 32-bit
 with Unsupported runtime (57)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.10.1
 @ ./js/components/search/searchgamepopup.scss 4:14-247

Comment: Please give more information about your environment. What version of Node, npm, OS e.t.c. Have you tried remove `node_modules` and run `npm install` ?

Comment: I am running on windows 7  which is 32 bit. I am now sure How to check Node and npm version. I have not run npm install